# ExtJS panel append html

Tags: javascript, dom, extjs, extjs4

I have an extjs4 panel created using this config object.

```
{ 
    title : 'Messages',
    region : 'north',
    height : 200,
    minSize : 75,
    maxSize : 250,
    cmargins : '0 0 5 0',
    html : '<i>Chat started on ' +  Ext.Date.format(dt, EI.datePattern)  + '</i>'
}
```

Now I want to append more html on it. For example I want to append

```
<p><span class="user">me:</span><span class="how are you?"></span></p>
```

Sometimes I could append using

```
 thePanel.body.insertHtml("beforeEnd", chatHtml);
```

But I see sometimes `.body` is not set!! So I can not execute the above code. What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: panel.body isn't available until the render event fires. When do you try to call insertHtml?

Comment: @EricCook right you are. I have fixed it by adding a .show() to the container window. Could you tell how can I render a panel or container  window manually?

Comment: I posted a more complete explanation as an answer. Hopefully that covers what you need but if I missed something, let me know so I can narrow it down a bit more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The body element of a panel isn't available until after the panel's render event has fired. This is the same for all elements that are listed under the `childEls` config of any component.

There are a few different ways an element can be rendered. This isn't a comprehensive list.

1. If a component is a child item of a container, then the component will be rendered when the parent container renders. The exception to this is containers using card layout, such as a tab panel, when using the `deferredRender` config.
2. If a component is *not* a child of a container, but it is using the `renderTo` config, it will be rendered upon construction, even if it is hidden.
3. If a non-floating component is using the `autoRender` config, that component will render the first time it is shown, such as with `panel.show()`. If it is using both `autoRender` and `autoShow` then it will be rendered upon construction.
4. Floating components such as windows default to `autoShow: false` and `autoRender: true`, so they will not render until you call `win.show()`. If you set `autoShow` to true, it will render on creation.
5. Floating components using the `renderTo` config will render on creation and stay hidden, unless also using `autoShow` as mentioned above.

It sounds like you have a panel that is a child of a window, correct? To get that panel to render immediately but stay hidden, set `renderTo: Ext.getBody()` on the parent window.

Alternatively, you can still access the `panel.html` property before the panel is rendered, and any changes will be reflected when the window is shown. So if you need to access the inner content but you can't guarantee the panel has been rendered, you might do something like this:

```
if (panel.body) {
    panel.body.insertHtml("beforeEnd", chatHtml);
} else {
    panel.html += chatHtml;
}
```

One last thing. If you set the `html` config of a panel then render it, there will be an extra div called the `clearEl` after your original content. Calling `panel.body.insertHtml()` after render will place the new HTML after this div. This may or may not be a problem for you, but I thought I'd mention it anyway.

Comment: The *extra div* element thing was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try using thePanel.getTargetEl()

From the source:

```
getTargetEl: function() {
    var me = this;
    return me.body || me.protoBody || me.frameBody || me.el;
}
```